# Grid formating format field in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I'm new to bootstrap and I have some problems in formatting my grid. I'd like to have form-horizontal for my email and password fields. For the address I'd like to have a more traditional layout as given. How can I combine the two? Unfortunately it gets screwed up the way I used it (as Bootstrap writes `class="form-horizontal"`needs to go into the `<form>` tag. But afaik I can use only one form to work probably with method=post.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="De">
<head>
  <title>Titel</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Titel</h1>
  <p>Bitte erfasse Deine persönlichen Angaben:</p>
  <form role="form" action="/registrieren" method="post">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender">Frau</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender">Mann</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender">Anderes</label>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="usr">Vorname:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vorname" name="vorname">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="usr">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="usr">Strasse:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="strasse" name="strasse">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
                <label for="usr">PLZ:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="plz" name="plz">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="usr">Ort:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ort" name="ort">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2"  for="usr">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it should look:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add .form-horizontal to the actual `<form>` element, you can make a `<div>` with class .form-horizontal and wrap the form elements that you want to have the horizontal style within it.

```
<form>
  <!-- Normal form inputs outside the div -->
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-horizontal>
     <!-- Form inputs that you want to have horizontal layout -->
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi. It's not on an element it's used currently in `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">` as written on w3schools.

Comment: @empedokles i've just updated my answer to show this

Comment: I've updated the HTML above, but it still looks awkward. Can you have a glance?

Comment: @empedokles from your question, that is how you want it to look? Traditional layout for address fields, & form-horizontal layout for email & password fields. Can you possibly make a drawing or such of how you need it to look?

Comment: Unfortunately the spacing doesn't look evenly. There is too less spacing between the option fields and the adress fields. The Email field is touching the place field in my browser. Password should be left aligned. I will add a mockup above.